# Python script not executing completely when called from PHP in a webpage?

Tags: php, python

Python script only executes first few lines of code when it is called from PHP whereas it is executing perfectly when it is executed from the command line.
I am running PHP through xampp server on windows. I have researched a lot about this but I have not been able to find anything helpful that would solve my problem. I am on the clock here as I have to submit this to my boss in the morning, any help would be highly appreciated.
Following is the code snippet I am using to execute the python script from PHP.

```
$cmd = 'python C:\xampp\htdocs\aws_engine\images\aws_engine_script.py';
    $command = escapeshellcmd($cmd);
        //$run =  shell_exec($command);
        $pid = popen( $command,"r");
        while( !feof( $pid ) )
        {
            echo fread($pid, 256);
           flush();
           ob_flush();
           usleep(100000);
        }
        pclose($pid);
```

here is my python script which establishes a connection with AWS S3 and uploads image file from a directory to S3 bucket but, my script stops after second print statement:

```
#header files
import os  
import tinys3
import glob
from subprocess import check_output
from time import gmtime, strftime

#Providing AWS Access and Secret key credentials
print('Establishing connection to S3..')
conn = tinys3.Connection('XXXXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXXXXX',tls=True)

print('Connection established & uploading files...')

#loop for uploading image files with in a local directory of extensions PNG, JPG & JPEG 
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('C:/xampp/htdocs/aws_engine/images/'):
    for f in filenames:
        if f.endswith(".jpg") or f.endswith(".jpeg"):
            k = open(f,'rb')
            conn.upload(f,k,'deeplearning-test-bucketsppu')
            print (f)

print('\n All files Uploaded successfully !')
```

Comment: Can you paste the part of the Python script where execution stops?

Comment: Check to make sure that Apache or whichever Web Server you are using to do this has permissions to the python file. If you want to run Python from Apache I would suggest looking into the WSGI plugin.

Comment: @sneep check my post now! Thanks

Comment: @Darney Thanks for ur advice can you give me any link or reference to WSGI plugin?

Comment: I tried executing the PHP file. The Python script got called and worked until the end. I would recommend looking at the `STDERR` output of the Python script to find out why it might have stopped. Maybe try adding `2>&1` to the python command (and temporarily remove `escapeshellcommand`) to redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT` if you can't see `STDERR` otherwise. (Not 100% sure if this works in Windows.)